# JFileChooser not showing text files

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filechooser

For some reason whenever I try to select a text file, it does not show up in the file chooser even though there is clearly a text file in the directory. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
package me.riley.logreader;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class LogReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActionListeners actions = new ActionListeners();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Log Reader");

        //Window options 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Adds the panel to the frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        //Creates the button and places it inside the panel
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Here");
        button.setLocation(10, 10);
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(actions);

        //Allows user to open a text file
        JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
        filechooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt", "txt"));
        filechooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a text file");
        filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        }

    }
```

Comment: `JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've set the FileSelectionMode to DIRECTORIES_ONLY.

remove `filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);` and it should work.